# pl/sql stored update procedure in oracle apex

Tags: oracle

I observed some really weird  update problem with my pl/sql stored procedure here's the code:

```
create or replace procedure "UPDATECURRENTOFFICE"
(trans_pk IN NUMBER,
office_pk IN NUMBER)
is
BEGIN
UPDATE TRANSACTION
SET TRANSACTION.OFFICE_PK_CURRENT = office_pk
WHERE TRANSACTION.TRANS_PK = trans_pk;
end;​
```

it ends up updating every record in the table instead of just only one record. im using this pl/sql procedure inside a process with a process point of submit - after computations and validation.. Im new with apex, and I find it really hard making online systems with it. please help me T.T

Answer (score 0):

Change the parameter name.
The sql parser inside PL/SQL for the query

```
UPDATE TRANSACTION
SET TRANSACTION.OFFICE_PK_CURRENT = office_pk
WHERE TRANSACTION.TRANS_PK = trans_pk;
```

recognizes trans_pk as the column trans_pk not the pl/sql variable. So the WHERE condition is read as WHERE TRANS_PK=TRANS_PK witch means WHERE TRANS_PK IS NOT NULL

The following should work

```
create or replace procedure "UPDATECURRENTOFFICE"
(inp_trans_pk IN NUMBER,
office_pk IN NUMBER)
is
BEGIN
UPDATE TRANSACTION
SET TRANSACTION.OFFICE_PK_CURRENT = office_pk
WHERE TRANSACTION.TRANS_PK = inp_trans_pk;
end;​
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have a column in your table and a parameter to your stored procedure both called `TRANS_PK`.  You may have written your parameter `trans_pk`, but in Oracle, [identifiers (such as parameter names) are case-insensitive](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_procedures.htm#sthref1190).

It happens that in your query, the name `trans_pk` is recognised as a column name rather than a parameter name.  So your query will update every row where the `TRANS_PK` value equals the `TRANS_PK` value.  This will be every row in the table, unless there are any rows where `TRANS_PK` is not `NULL`.  However, given the name of this column I suspect it's part of the primary key of the `TRANSACTION` table and so won't contain any `NULL` values.

If you use a prefix for function/procedure parameter names, such as `p_`, this problem goes away.  Here's a fixed version of your stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure "UPDATECURRENTOFFICE"
(p_trans_pk IN NUMBER,
p_office_pk IN NUMBER)
is
BEGIN
UPDATE TRANSACTION
SET TRANSACTION.OFFICE_PK_CURRENT = p_office_pk
WHERE TRANSACTION.TRANS_PK = p_trans_pk;
end;​
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rename the parameter, but best practice is to **always** use aliases when using SQL in PL/SQL, e.g.:

```
create or replace procedure "UPDATECURRENTOFFICE"
(trans_pk IN NUMBER,
office_pk IN NUMBER)
is
BEGIN
UPDATE TRANSACTION
SET TRANSACTION.OFFICE_PK_CURRENT = UPDATECURRENTOFFICE.office_pk
WHERE TRANSACTION.TRANS_PK = UPDATECURRENTOFFICE.trans_pk;
end;​
```

This code is resilient to unexpected changes to the table structure.